# Output zip file to a specific directory, other than the directory of the script

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to zip contents of the `src` folder and save the zip file in the `dst` folder:

```
import shutil

src = '/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/sampler_proj/sampler/media/audio/slices/'
dst = '/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/sampler_proj/sampler/media/audio/zipped/'

shutil.make_archive('samples', 'zip', base_dir=src, root_dir=dst)
```

However, the `samples.zip` file is not being saved to the `dst` folder, but to the folder in which my script resides, that is `/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/sampler_proj/sampler/media/audio/`.

How can I fix it?

I have looked at some other SO threads and the `shutil` docs, but the definitions of `root_dir` and `base_dir` are quite confusing.

Comment: Why not simply move the file after it is created?

Comment: I could do this as a last resort, but it does not feel very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive):

> shutil.make_archive(base_name, format[, root_dir[, base_dir[, verbose[, dry_run[, owner[, group[, logger]]]]]]])
>   Create an archive file (such as zip or tar) and return its name.
>   **base_name is the name of the file to create, including the path, minus any format-specific extension.** format is the archive format: one of “zip” (if the zlib module is available), “tar”, “gztar” (if the zlib module is available), “bztar” (if the bz2 module is available), or “xztar” (if the lzma module is available).

(enphasis in bold is mine).

The first argument should include the full destination path, if you do not want the file to be in your current directory.
So you are assigning a wrong directory to `root_dir` I guess. According to the docs, `root_dir` should be:

> root_dir is a directory that will be the root directory of the archive; for example, we typically chdir into root_dir before creating the archive.

Try to do:

```
src = '/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/sampler_proj/sampler/media/audio/slices/'
dst = '/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/sampler_proj/sampler/media/audio/zipped/'
pth = os.path.join(dst, 'samples')
shutil.make_archive(pth, 'zip', root_dir=src, base_dir=src)
```

In most cases, `root_dir` and `base_dir` are the same directory, the one that you want to archive. It make a sense to provide both of them for more complex cases, which does not seem your case. For example, if you want to go into a directory, and then create separate archives of subdirectories through recursion.

Comment: Don't concatenate path elements as ordinary strings. Use `os.path.join()` instead.